# The application of tense agreement

Tags: sentence-meaning, sentence-structure, relative-clauses, sentence-usage, tense-agreement

Do the rules of sequence of tenses apply to an adjective clause? Can the tense of an adjective clause be different from the main clause? The examples are as follows.

> The latest preliminary report I’ve seen said that more than 100 people had died in Mexico City alone.

> We asked a handful of writers who have covered technology for The New Yorker to discuss these questions over e-mail and suggest something like a way forward.

> The growth and shifting demographics brought a vibrancy to the local community that has been embraced by people of different races and backgrounds.

Comment: What is an adjective clause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adjective clauses add detail, often serving to clarify or identify someone or something. As they are additional detail, they are often parenthetical. For example:

> My brother, *whom you met last year*, is coming home tomorrow.

If I understand your question correctly, you are asking if the tense of an adjective clause can differ from the main clause. As you can see from my example, it is quite acceptable to use an event from the past (last year) to add detail in a statement about the future (tomorrow). The verbs "met" and "is coming" are appropriate to those tenses.

However, I don't see that in any of your examples:

> We **asked** a handful of writers (*who **have covered** technology for The New Yorker*) to discuss these questions over e-mail and suggest something like a way forward.

This detail about the past work of the writers adds relevant detail. But everything else is in the past tense, too - they were '*asked*' (past tense) to have a discussion.

> The growth and shifting demographics brought a vibrancy to the local community *that has been embraced by people of different races and backgrounds*.

I don't see a problem here either - the vibrancy was "brought", and it "has been embraced". I don't see a mix of tenses?

> The latest preliminary report *I’ve seen* said that more than 100 people had died in Mexico City alone.

This isn't a very well-written sentence. I don't like "the latest report I've seen" - it would me more idiomatic to say "*the last report that I saw*. Either way, the report was "seen" in the past, and it "said" that people "died". All past tense, so I don't know why you think the tenses are different?